# Dundas dashboards image hover interactions

Tags: c#, dundas

In Dundas dashboard i have a small image that if you hover your mouse over it the image   must appear. Can anybody help me with the hover interaction coding please.

Answer (score 1):

Put something like this in the Hover or MouseEnter interaction of the Image control:

```
sender.Url = new DashboardImageUrl("http://www.example.com/myimage.png");
```

**Edit:** If you want to show a dashboard inside another dashboard, you can use the Dashblock Viewer control.  However, that control can only show Dashblocks, not full Dashboards.

If you want to show the dashboard in some sort of pop-up or hover, you can use the `services.ShowDashboardDialog` or `services.ShowDashboardPopup` overloads.

Comment: That doesnt work what i realy want is : I have a tille dashboard and then a main dashboard so if you hover over a btton, image or lable i want the smaler tille dashboard to apear could you help me with this

Comment: I modified my answer to try and answer this question.